# Android: Audio recordings appear with different file names but same content

Tags: java, android, listview

I already looked around here but was not able to find anything that helped, that's why I posted this

So basically what I'm trying to do is allow the user to record audio as long as the button is held down and will add the recording to a ListView once the user is done. Names are assigned to the recordings using `new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z")` so they'll be different.

> Example: First file will be Thu, 1 Jan 2016 00:00:01 -0000.mp3
>
> and the second file will be Thu, 1 Jan 2016 00:00:02 -0000.mp3

I've already got the appearing on ListView part down but for some reason, anytime I record, although the recordings appear on the ListView as recordings with different names, when I touch them to play, all files are the same audio file. I'm not sure what is going on. I have spent some time looking but I'm not sure why. I'm relatively new to Android Development so my apologies if it happens to be something minor but anyway, here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private MediaRecorder myAudioRecorder;
    String nameOfRecording; // name of recording (for ListView)
    String outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + nameOfRecording;

    // for list of recordings
    ListView ResultsListView;
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>(); // stores names of mp3 files.


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ResultsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ResultsListView);
        listRecordings();

        // handles "record" and "stop"
        final ImageButton roundButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_button);

        roundButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    Log.i("Touched", "Recording");

                    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
                    Date now = new Date();
                    nameOfRecording = formatter.format(now) + ".mp3";

                    myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                    myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                    myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                    myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
                    myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);
                    startRecording();
                }


                else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                {
                    stopRecording();
                    Log.i("Released", "Stopped");

                    // refresh the ResultsListView
                    lines.add(nameOfRecording); // add name of recording to ArrayList.
                    listRecordings(); // refreshes the listView

                    ResultsListView.setOnItemClickListener(
                        new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
                            {
                                String touchedRecording = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Playing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                playRecording(touchedRecording);
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

This is the `playRecording` method()

```
public void playRecording(String touchedRecording)
{
    touchedRecording = nameOfRecording;

    MediaPlayer m = new MediaPlayer();

    try {
        m.setDataSource(outputFile);
    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        m.prepare();
    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    m.start();
}
```

I don't get why the file names show up as different files but have the same audio in them. I'm relatively new to Android Development so sorry if it's actually just something minor. Anyone know what is going on? Thank you very much.

*P.S. I'm also having a MediaPlayer not released properly error anytime I close the app but I should be able to figure that out. But any input regarding that too is not high priority but still welcome.*